# Install nodejs sharp on azure 32bit

Tags: node.js, azure, node-gyp

I am trying to deploy a node.js project to Azure Web Apps (free tier) and one of its dependencies is sharp: https://github.com/lovell/sharp

When going through the deploy process I get:

```
ERROR: Intel Architecture 32-bit systems require manual installation - please see http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/install/
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('./binding').download_vips()"' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit    (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
```

I've tried running the command listed on the sharp documentation in the online Azure console `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lovell/sharp/master/preinstall.sh | sudo bash -` (I removed the `sudo` before trying though because Azure didn't like that). But I got an error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 91: type: pkg-config: not found
(23) Failed writing body
```

So nothing appears to be working. Unfortunately I can't switch my environment to x64 as it appears that free tier users are restricted to the 32bit environment. Any way I can get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While most modules are simply plain-text JavaScript files, some modules are platform-specific binary images. These modules are compiled at install time, usually by using Python and node-gyp
>   Azure App Service does not support all native modules and might fail at compiling those with very specific prerequisites.

the description is from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/.

You can install the sharp in windows 32 platform on your local environment, and deploy your application to Azure with the `node_modules` folder which contains the compiled module.

You can refer to https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/379 for install the sharp module on 32-bit Windows environment.

Comment: Don't I need to have a 32bit installation of Windows? I only have access to 64 bit installations and I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up a VM just for this.

Comment: according https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/226, you can try to add the variable in command `npm install --arch=ia32` to force it to 32-bit